# Angular 7 material + openlayers: points are drawn in wrong position on display

Tags: openlayers, angular7

I'm developing a web gis application and for now I want just that on users' click a point is displayed. This is the code I'm using:

ts file `

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  map: OlMap;
  source: OSM;
  layers: [OlTileLayer, OlVectorLayer, OlVectorLayer]; //  OlTileLayer;
  beVectSource: OlVectorSource;
  view: OlView;
  vectorSource: OlVectorSource;
  marker: OlFeature;
  markers: [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const markerStyle = new OlStyle({
      image: new OlIcon(/**  {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
        src: 'https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/c/c5/Orienteering-icon-16px.png'
      }))
    });
    /*this.marker = new OlFeature({
      geometry: new OlPoint(fromLonLat([11.1822, 43.6699 ]))
    });*/

    this.source = new OSM();

    this.vectorSource = new OlVectorSource({
      // features: [this.marker]
    });

    this.beVectSource = new OlVectorSource({

    });

    this.layers = [
      new OlTileLayer({
      source: this.source,
      // minResolution: 200,
      // maxResolution: 2000,
      projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }),
    new OlVectorLayer({
      source: this.beVectSource,
      projection : 'EPSG:3857',
      style: markerStyle
    }),
    new OlVectorLayer({
      source: this.vectorSource,
      projection : 'EPSG:3857',
      style: markerStyle
    }),
  ],

    this.view = new OlView({
      // center: fromLonLat([11.1722, 43.5599 ]),
      zoom: 7,
      minZoom: 6,
      center: fromLonLat([11.1722, 43.5599 ]), // transform([11.1722, 43.5599 ], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: this.layers,
      view: this.view,
    });
    this.map.on('click', (args) => {

      /*this.map.getInteractions().getArray().forEach(function(interaction) {
        if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom) {
          this.map
        }
      });*/
      console.log(args);
      // const lonlat = tranform(args.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
      const lonlat = toLonLat(args.coordinate);
      const longitude = parseFloat(lonlat[0]);
      const latitude = parseFloat(lonlat[1]);
      const point: OlPoint = new OlPoint(fromLonLat([longitude, latitude])); // transform([longitude, latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
      const feature = new OlFeature({
        geometry: point,
      });
      this.vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    });
  }

  addToBeVectSource(point: OlPoint) {
    this.beVectSource.addFeature(point);
  }

}`
```

html file

```
<mat-card >
    <mat-card-content>
        <div id="map" >
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Salva posizione</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

in the app component.html:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile class="mapTile" >
          <app-map></app-map>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

when map gets clicked a new point is added. The problem is that if I mantain map component selector inside  tag the map appears somehow less focused with place names smaller and looking more at distance. The problem it's also that icons don't appear where I clicked but on the top-right. Instead if I place the selector outside  and  map get better focused with all the elements displayed with the right dimension and the icons appear on the clicked place. Below two images with the two different case where the red point stays for the click point.

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7NiM.jpg)

[desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpl8m.jpg)

As one can see the first image looks somehow less zoomed and the icon is displayed on the top right of the red circle, while in the second one the circle overlap the icon and the map in general looks more focused. This happens even if the zoom level is the same in both case so the problem appears to be provoked by some interaction between angular material grid list and openlayers. Any suggestion that doesn't imply the dismission of grid list?

Comment: Your screenshots don't show the icon used in your code.  Were you using another image which contained padding on one side?

Comment: Not sure that I've understood your question... the icon is the little square white and yellow on top-right of the point that marks cursor's position in both the images. In any case I don't  think that the problem is related to the padding of the img as I tried also using Circle object instead of OlIcon having the same result.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshots get reduced and it wasn't very conspicuous.  I've tried your style and onclick code in plain OpenLayers and it works perfectly.  Always being misplaced by the same number of pixels does suggest a style problem, possibly browser or environment specific, maybe explicitly specifying the size or imageSize in the icon style will make a difference (even specify something smaller than 16 and see if it has any effect).

Comment: Thank for your suggestion Mike, I've tried but nothing changes... in any case I've found the problem and it appears to be something related to angular material grid list that I use in the app component. I'm updating the question

Comment: You may need to update the map size after the view has has been initialized. So, add `MapComponent implements AfterViewInit` and also add method `ngAfterViewInit(): void { this.map.updateSize(); }`